# Java программа операций для работы с файлами

Tags: java, java-8

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Если в пути файла не указано расширение, то он автоматически создаёт расширение .txt
Как сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Просто проверяете последнюю точку

```
String filename = "myFile";
String extension = "txt";
int lastIndexOf = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
if (lastIndexOf == -1) {
    filename = filename + "."+extension;
} else if(lastIndexOf == filename.length()-1){
    filename = filename + extension;
}
System.out.println(filename);
```